# Embed parts of an HTML Website

Tags: html, iframe, embed

For my School we use a homework website called HomeLogic. I want to take the assignments block of that website and put it into a custom Homepage that I have made.

Here is the code of the "Assignments" frame.

```
<frame name="Assignments" id="Assignments" src="Home_Assignments.asp?"
scrolling="auto" noresize="" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0">
```

But there is one problem. To enter into this Website you would need to enter a username and a password. How can I embed this frame into my homepage and make it automatically login so I can see the assignments? Thanks in advance, Jake.